# URL-rewrite domain to page

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a web application that can be accessed by for example: someapp.example.com. A specific subdirectory of pages should however be accessible by anotherexample.com. How can I accomplish this via URL rewriting? Please note that the subdirectory's pages are not accessible from the someapp.example.com.

I already tried something like thing, resulting in a URL rewrite 500.50 error:

```
(?=www\.)?anotherexample\.com(?=\.localtest\.me)?
```

Answer (score 0):

You would set up 2 websites and corresponding virtual directories for the sub directory, each serving the set of pages required. There is no need to use URL rewriting from what I can see.

Comment: Because of technical reasons, I'd prefer to have the same web application for the url.